# PCIe: how to transfer metadata with minimum overheads

Tags: pci-e

Lets say I have an existing PCIe system - say a host CPU connected to a PCIe NIC card. I would like to transfer some metadata between host and device - say some debug information that I want to transfer on a per packet basis. I would like to avoid the overhead of using extra message or memory transactions for this purpose.

Is there some way I can transfer metadata as part of regular Memory Read/Write TLPs ?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific - you can't transfer anything over PCIe while also avoiding the overhead of transferring anything over PCIe ("using an extra message or memory transaction for this purpose").

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you would like to add some data in every TLP you send right? TLP will be constructed by your controller. So you cannot alter any standard field to include your data. Do you have any sideband signals available with the device? Maybe that can be used. Just a thought. Also the metadata you send to the device, who will parse that? Do you have the firmware of the NIC with you which you can edit to parse the meta data? Also how do you know your device PCIe layer will not treat this as malformed TLP and generate a uncorrectable non-fatal error?

Comment: There is a thing called a TLP prefix. Maybe you can define a custom TLP prefix?

Comment: I was looking for some way to annotate extra information in a standard TLP packet. TLP prefix seems to be meant just for that. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: If you have found a way to do this, can you please write an answer describing it?